# Почему в React.js в событии onKeyUp не работает event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста, вот код

```
<input type="text" placeholder={item.name} onKeyUp={self.checkName} />
checkName: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();      
},
```

Почему методе event.preventDefault(); не отрабатывает, то есть я как печатал так и печатаю, а если я поменю keyUp , к примеру на keyDown, то тогда норм, не могу вводить символы.

Comment: Потому что добавление в `<input>` введённого символа происходит при `keydown`. В качестве аналогии: "у меня есть кастрюля. Если я сначала накрываю её крышкой, а потом лью в неё воду, то вода в кастрюлю не попадает. А если сначала налью воду в кастрюлю, а потом закрываю её крышкой, то почему-то вода в кастрюле есть".

Comment: Што???? onKeyUp работает по тому же принципу, что и keyDown, только разница в том, что keyDown получает предыдущее значение введенное пользователем, а onKeyUp - то что пользователь ввел в данный момент

Comment: Ещё раз: `event.preventDefault();` в `keyup` никоим образом не запретит ввод символа, потому что к моменту появления события `keyup` (при отпускании клавиши) нажатый символ уже находится в `<input>`.

Comment: а как же тогда реализовать так, чтоб запретить вводить пользователю символы, которые не соответствуют регулярному выражению?

Comment: используйте событие `keypress`

Comment: Добавить обработчик события `keyup`, в нём проверять и в нём же запрещать, если нужно.

Comment: @ThisMan `keypress` не срабатывает для неcимвольных клавиш - порой, это важно.

Comment: @ну так, цель как раз проверять символ на совпадение с регуляркой, как вы несимвольные то проверите? Поэтому как раз подходит